# Change StorageManager's default mount point from /mnt/obb to /mnt/data

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I am following [this obb sample](https://github.com/wiliwe/android-obb-example/tree/master/OBB-APK-Source) to load a native library from an obb file. But I am seeing following error on `System.load(mylib.getAbsolutePath())` call.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/mnt/obb/fcc93fcbaf5acfc/mylibs.so" needed or dlopened by 
"/system/lib/libnativeloader.so" is not accessible for the namespace "classloader-namespace" 
    [name="classloader-namespace", ld_library_paths="", default_library_paths="", permitted_paths="/data:/mnt/expand:/data/data/com.example"]
```

But as far as I understood, [StorageManager#mountObb()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager#mountObb(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.storage.OnObbStateChangeListener)) by default mounting to ***/mnt/obb***. Is there a way I can instruct **StorageManager** to mount the obb at **/mnt/data** ?

Comment: "I am following this obb sample to load a native library from an obb file" -- FWIW, that would seem to violate the Google Play rules about code distribution.

Comment: @CommonsWare Agrees with you, it's more of an experiment as the doc (https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files) is pretty vague about obb contents